# NSIS MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME custom info text

Tags: nsis

How to override info text on uninstaller welcome page (MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME)?
I used MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT for installer welcome page. But I cannot find solution for uninstaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MUI_TEXT_WELCOME_INFO_TEXT` is not documented as something you can set.

The MUI documentation tells you which defines you can set and where they apply:

> Page settings apply to a single page and should be set before inserting a page macro. **The same settings can be used for installer and uninstaller pages**.

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "Blahblah install $(^NameDA).$\r$\n$\r$\nBlah blah blah"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TEXT "Blahblah uninstall $(^NameDA).$\r$\n$\r$\nBlah blah blah"
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
```